# How to attach TKinter Scrollbar in Listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I'm trying to create a listbox with a scrollbar attached to it. I've seen some similar questions here, I've followed them and tried to make the same, but their solutions are not working for me.

The problem is in these line:

```
total_results_listbox.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
total_results_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

If I omit the line:

```
total_results_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

then I can see only the listbox. And if I omit the line:

```
total_results_listbox.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
```

then I can see only the scrollbar.
Could you figure out why I'm getting this?

My entire code is this:

```
def create_results_frame(root):
    results_frame = Frame(root)

    total_results_listbox = Listbox(results_frame,background='white')
    total_results_scrollbar = Scrollbar(total_results_listbox, orient=VERTICAL)
    total_results_listbox.config(yscrollcommand=total_results_scrollbar.set)
    total_results_scrollbar.configure(command=total_results_listbox.yview)

    recipes_result = ["honey pancake", "american pancake1", "american pancake2", "american pancake3", "american pancake4",
              "american pancake5", "american pancake6", "american pancake7", "american pancake8",
              "american pancake9", "american pancake10", "american pancake11", "american pancake12"]

    for recipe in recipes_result:
        total_results_listbox.insert(END, recipe)

    total_results_listbox.grid(row=0, sticky=W)
    total_results_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)

    return results_frame
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there, just a few things:

- The scrollbar should be a child of the frame, not the listbox:
  `total_results_scrollbar = Scrollbar(results_frame, orient=VERTICAL)`
- When you grid the listbox, make sure it sticks north south: `total_results_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=NS)`